# Kivy Button in Popup not calling function

Tags: python, kivy

Here's the code that has the problem:

```
Class Screen1(Screen):
    def win(self):
        if win == True:
             Self.open_popup()

    def open_popup(self):
        content = BoxLayout()
        button = Button(text="restart", on_press=self.retry(), 
        on_release=self.dismiss() )
        content.add_widget(button)
        self.popup = Popup(title="Popup", content=content)

    def retry(self):
        #resets game
```

It gives me the error "none is not callable" and "Screen1 has no attribute dismiss" what am I doing wrong?

Also, I have had to call the popup like this and not in a .kv file because that for some reason didn't work with screen manager

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Question** It gives me the error "none is not callable" and "Screen1 has no attribute dismiss" what am I doing wrong?

**Answer** Popup has bindable functions such as open and dismiss.

**Question** Also, I have had to call the popup like this and not in a .kv file because that for some reason didn't work with screen manager

**Answer** You can create a class of Popup widget, and define all the widgets in the kv file. Please refer to the example below for details.

## Example

### main.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.properties import BooleanProperty
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup


class MessageBox(Popup):
    def __init__(self, obj, **kwargs):
        super(MessageBox, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.obj = obj


class Screen1(Screen):
    win = BooleanProperty(True)

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Screen1, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.name = "screen1"
        self.display_winner()

    def display_winner(self):
        if self.win:
            popup = MessageBox(self)    # pass screen1 object
            popup.open()

    def retry(self):
        print("Reset Game")


class ScreenManagement(ScreenManager):
    pass


class TestApp(App):
    title = "Kivy Screen Manager & Popup Demo"

    def build(self):
        return ScreenManagement()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    TestApp().run()
```

### test.kv

```
#:kivy 1.10.0

<MessageBox>:
    title: "Popup"
    size_hint: None, None
    size: 400, 400
    auto_dismiss: False

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        Label:
            text: "Player 1 is the winner!"
        Button:
            size_hint: 1, 0.2
            text: "restart"
            on_press: root.obj.retry()
            on_release: root.dismiss()

<ScreenManagement>:
    Screen1:

<Screen1>:
    name: "screen1"
```

### Output

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

1)

```
on_press=self.retry()
```

You're calling `self.retry` function here and pass it's result as `on_press`. You should pass function itself:

```
on_press=self.retry
```

2)

```
self.dismiss()
```

You're trying to call function `self.dismiss` on `Screen` object. Screen doesn't have this method, `Popup` does. You probably want something like this:

```
content = BoxLayout()
self.popup = Popup(
    title="Popup", 
    content=content
)
button = Button(
    text="restart",
    on_press=self.retry,
    on_release=self.popup.dismiss
)
content.add_widget(button)
```